# How to return maximum occurrence character in a List ? by python. X = ['(a,20)','(b,30)','(c,15)','(d,45)']

Tags: python, list, max

In list `X = ['(a,20)','(b,30)','(c,15)','(d,45)']`
In list X, a occurred 20 times, b occurred 30 times, c occurred 15 times, d occurred 45 times
How can I return the most occurrence character as d ? could you tell me please.

Comment: Is this really the format of your data?

Answer (score 3):

```
In [295]: L
Out[295]: [('a', 20), ('b', 30), ('c', 15), ('d', 45)]

In [296]: max(L, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
Out[296]: ('d', 45)
```

If your data really is stringified tuples in a list:

```
In [300]: L = ['(a,20)','(b,30)','(c,15)','(d,45)']

In [301]: max(L, key=lambda s: int(s.rstrip(")").split(',')[1]))
Out[301]: '(d,45)'
```

Comment: just as a remark: the OPs tuples are strings, which is an error i guess.

Comment: @DonQuestion: Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't notice it before

Answer (score 2):

you can also use a lambda function:

```
max(L, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: its not displaying the expected result

Comment: oh sorry, you are right. thanks. the reason is that the elemetns are strings, see also the answer by @inspectorG4dget.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function below.

```
import sys
sys.stdin = open('in.txt', 'r')

def max_occurrence_element(p):
    cnt = {}
    for item in p:
        cnt.setdefault(item, 0)
        cnt[item] += 1
    return max(cnt.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])[0]

print max_occurrence_element(map(int, raw_input().split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      python 3.2
      from itertools import Counter

      lis=['(a,20)','(b,30)','(c,15)','(d,45)','(d,45)','(d,45)','(d,45)']
      mx=Counter(lis)
      mx.most_common()[0]
```